# Invoke method with Reflection from an exe on a network drive

Tags: c#, security, reflection

I am trying to invoke a method using Reflection within an exe on a network drive, but I get the following exception.

> [2013-07-12 11:58:54 AM] The following error occured :Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation. Inner Exception
>   :System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.    at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)    at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options)    at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append)    at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding
>   encoding, Int32 bufferSize)    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String
>   path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)    at
>   System.IO.File.AppendAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding
>   encoding)    at System.IO.File.AppendAllText(String path, String
>   contents)    at ccc.ControllerBO.ExecuteTest()

I have read up on the Security Settings, but I do not want to install the invoker EXE and cannot find a solution.

What can I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the executable to a place local to your own assembly and invoke it from there.

Comment: Easiest way out, make temp local folder and copy exe and dependencies over.

Answer (score 0):

You can create evidence instance and pass it to LoadForm method, like this:

```
#if NET35
            var evidence = new System.Security.Policy.Evidence();
            evidence.AddHost(new System.Security.Policy.Url(assemblyPath));
            evidence.AddHost(new System.Security.Policy.Zone(System.Security.SecurityZone.MyComputer));
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath, evidence);                        
#elif NET40
            var evidence = new System.Security.Policy.Evidence();
            evidence.AddHostEvidence(new System.Security.Policy.Url(assemblyPath));
            evidence.AddHostEvidence(new System.Security.Policy.Zone(System.Security.SecurityZone.MyComputer));
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);                        
#endif
```

where assemblyPath - is a full path to file with an assembly (for e.g. on network drive).

Comment: Okay, so if I add the hosts, i cannot load in the installed dlls. Should I add the installed dlls as well?

Comment: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

Comment: I've tested a short sample (for case .NE 3.5). I have strong-named assembly (test.dll) and sample application (test.exe).
I load assembly via reflection and call method from class in dll.
It works fine in all cases:
1. exe and dll are both placed in network share
2. exe and dll are both placed in local folder
3. exe is in local folder and dll is in gac.